# Unable to open links in new tab on Dolphin

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire, dolphin-browser

I am running Andrond 2.2 on HTC Desire.

I was using Dolphin HD til recently. All was well until I upgraded the browser to the current version, which is 10.2.3. It says `previous Dolphin Browser HD` in brackets.

Since then, the long press doesn't work like it used to. The menu just has `select text`, `find on page`, and `close tab`. I can't open links in new tabs. I am finding it extremely hard to browse. The stock browser is worse.

Reinstalling didn't help.

What is wrong? How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

They may be javascript links that Dolphin will execute, but will not provide context menu for as links.  Also we are on 11.2.3 now so if there was a problem with normal links in 10.2.3 it may have been resolved.

Here is a page, [001 Tab Capacity Test](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/firefox/tab_capacity/001_with_underscore.htm),  that has normal links such as underscored "04"  and some JavaScript links in shaded boxes, such as "loc:" at the top.

The context menu of the JavaScript link is what you would see for plain text, it would be nice to be able to use "Copy link URL" and be able to "Bookmark link" in the normal manner but that is not possible in Dolphin.

If you still have a problem with a page provide the url of a public webpage (no userid or password required) and the link involved so we can look at the source.

---

Optional material:
[Installing bookmarklets into Dolphin](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/dolphin/dolphin_mygestures.htm#dolphinbookmarklets) can be a bit tedious and round about, importing them from another browser may be easier.